# Automatic numbering field in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, templates

I'm creating a template with a section with figures/tables, and I would like to have them automatically numbered, e.g. Figure #1, Figure #2, etc. A user would copy/paste the template's format, and it will paste with the incremented number. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Insert Caption** it will enter Figure [#] where # is the next number in the series. If you copy and paste this info into a new file it will keep the correct order. If you add a new **Insert Caption** between current ones, it will update all #s.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to create a macro to insert selected file image and insert Caption and crossRef and option to Ctrl+A and F9 and save